# Can I assign a value to a Castle.Proxy object property via reflection?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, rhino-mocks, castle

I have a controller test base which I use to handle a lot of the redundant code in my testing.  Internally, it takes a generic `TDataSource` parameter which should be an interface containing the `IDbSet`s for EF code first.  At run time, the test base builds a mock TDataSource using RhinoMocks `_MockDataSource = MockRepository.GenerateMock(Of TDataSource)()`.  Then I use reflection to get all the IDbSet properties of the interface and assign mock db sets to them.  (NOTE: This works fine with a virtual class, just interfaces do not work).

When I try to set the value of one of the `IDbSet(Of TEntity)` properties with a call to `propertyInfo.SetValue(dataSource, mockDbSet, Nothing)`, it does not set the actual value.  There is no exception, it just does not work.  I assume this is because the object `dataSource` is not really a `TDataSource` like the type specifies, but a `Castle.Proxies.IFakeDataSourceForTestingProxyf53f1730dba4492f8cafb9c731133d32` which is somehow intercepting my call to `SetValue`.  How can I fix this!

Full code of the failing method below:

```
    Protected Sub InjectTestData(ParamArray data() As IEnumerable)
        Dim dataSourceType As Type = GetType(TDataSource)
        Dim dataSourceProperties() As PropertyInfo = dataSourceType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance)

        'match up supplied data and required data sets
        For i As Integer = LBound(data) To UBound(data) Step 1
            Dim [set] As IEnumerable = data(i)
            Dim setType As Type = [set].GetType()
            If Not setType.IsGenericType Then
                Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("Parameter {0} of the data array was not a generic IEnumerable, could not add to any IDbSet.", i))
            End If

            Dim modelType As Type = setType.GetGenericArguments(0)
            Dim dbSetType As Type = GetType(IDbSet(Of )).MakeGenericType({modelType})

            Dim foundDbSet As Boolean
            For Each [property] As PropertyInfo In dataSourceProperties
                If dbSetType.IsAssignableFrom([property].PropertyType) Then
                    Dim fakeDbSet As Object = CreateFakeDbSet(modelType, [set])
                    [property].SetValue(_MockDataSource, fakeDbSet, Nothing)
                    foundDbSet = True
                End If
            Next
            If Not foundDbSet Then Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("Could not find an IDbSet(Of {0}) property on {1} to match parameter {2}", modelType.Name, dataSourceType.Name, i))
        Next

        'add empty lists to any data sets which are still null
        For Each [property] As PropertyInfo In dataSourceProperties
            If [property].GetValue(_MockDataSource, Nothing) Is Nothing Then
                Dim modelType As Type = [property].PropertyType.GetGenericArguments(0)
                Dim fakeDbSet As Object = CreateFakeDbSet(modelType)
                [property].SetValue(_MockDataSource, fakeDbSet, Nothing)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why use reflection to set these properties?  Why not just be explicit and set the properties via the mocked instance?

Comment: I don't know which properties I'm setting until compile time when an inheritor specifies what class TDataSource is.  Then with reflection, I set mock values on all the IDbSet properties inside of TDataSource.